# HTML input type - number

Tags: html, css

I changed the type of Price to number but it has placed the label to the left, how can I correct this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imga1.png
[image]

```
 End Date* (YYYY-MM-DD)  <input type="text" name="eDate"><br>
        Price*       <input type="number" name="price"><br>
```

Comment: <input type="number" name="price" style="float:left;">

Comment: display:block worked for me, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple of things. Some more simple than others.

I know I've fixed this in the past by simply using  `<br>`

soo.. `Price*<br> <input type="number" name="price"><br>`

Let me know if that doesn't work, I can suggest other solutions, like using width, display: block and floats etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with either floating, expanding the width of the input field or using a label tag to then put that display:block; like for example this:

```css
label{display:block}
```

```html
<form>
<label for="eDate">End Date* (YYYY-MM-DD)</label>
<input type="text" name="eDate"/>
<label for="price">Price*</label>
<input type="number" name="price"/>
</form>
```

This would be the way I would handle it, but feel free to ask additional information if you'd require it!

Comment: Nice to hear that worked for you, it's also the first thing I would have done to get it fixed to be honest. So do please upvote/mark any of the answers as valid if they helped you ;)